# Export duplicated functions in two namespaces (C++)

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, export, duplicates

I have these two namespaces, each one containing a function with the same name, like

```
namespace group1 {
    void add(int arg) {
    }
}

namespace group2 {
    void add(bool arg) {
    }
}
```

and I specify this in the header with the declarations

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
    extern "C" {
#endif
    // My namespaces and functions prototypes here
#ifdef __cplusplus 
    }
#endif
```

and I am trying to export them into a DLL, with GCC. I get a warning about a conflict between them because they have the same name, then an error at linking time. I thought the name was mangled in the object file based on the arguments, too. I don't know if the linker cares about the namespace too. How could I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are C++ functions, you have to remove the `extern "C"` bracketing:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
    extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus 
    }
#endif
```

`extern "C"` tells the compiler "don't mangle this name"--but (as you say) you want the mangling.

Comment: Thanks. I was so wrong. I want all this to be C++, I don't even know why I exported it as C.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do that directly. When you use the `extern "C"`, you are declaring that the functions are exported as if they were C functions, not C++.

This means (among other things)

1. Namespaces are removed, and are not considered part of the name
2. No name mangling due to arguments is done

The best you can do is create extern "C" functions which redirect.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
    extern "C" {
#endif
    void group1_add(int arg);
    void group2_add(bool arg);
#ifdef __cplusplus 
    }
#endif
```

And the implementations of the wrapper functions would then use either `group1::add()` or `group2::add()` as appropriate.